# jquery add/remove input dynamically

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement a dynamic input field on jQuery. But nothing is happening in this code. Somehow i believe the error is syntax related, or at least related to jquery fundamentals so i apologize in advance.

```
var add = function(){
    var intID = $('#target').length+1;
    var row = $('<tr id=\"row'+intID+'\">row</tr>');
    var data_1 = $('<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"part'.intID.'\"/></td>');
    var data_2 = $('<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"pos'.intID.'\"/></td>');
    var remove_button = $('<td><input type=\"button\" onclick=\"$(this).parent().parent().remove()\"/></td>');
    $(row).append(data_1);
    $(row).append(data_2);
    $(row).append(remove_button);
    $('#target').append(row);
}
```

The target is an empty table and im trying to add and remove the appropriate rows.

Comment: I'm not clear what the use of period '.' is for in your statements ...id=\"row'.intID.'\">r...  should you use '+' to concat to a single string?

Comment: I fixed the concat error, but I still get no response from my code.

Comment: you've updated the question with one concat correction, but the two related to the input fields are still using the `.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are concatenating incorrectly. `.intID.` should be `+intID+`.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `.intID.` with `+intID+`